# How to use a Regex for a list of options, but each option can only be used once?

Tags: r, regex, text

I am trying to take a text file of Shakespeare's complete works and separate it into each work. I already created a list of all the works as they are formatted in the text, and created a regex which finds any one of the titles.

```
(?:THE SONNETS|ALL’S WELL THAT ENDS WELL)
```

And so on, including all of Shakespeare's works that are in the text.

The regex works as intended--it extracts all lines from the text which contain one of the titles. BUT there is a problem: in several cases (especially Cymbeline and King John), the name of the titular character at the beginning of their lines is exactly the same as the name of the play. So, I can fix this problem by only using each work once.

Is there a way I can write the regex to look for the titles, and then after it finds a specific title, take it out of the possibilities? Or will I have to do something more complicated than regex?

If it helps, I am specifically using `R`, and I know a decent amount about using `rebus` to create regex's.

TL;DR: I want the regex to find the first occurrence of each string in a list, in a larger text document. Can I do this with one regex, or will I need to generate multiple regex or iterate?

### Examples under here:

Example text file:

```
    THE SONNETS
    
    sonnet text
    sonnet text
    
    
    ALL'S WELL THAT ENDS WELL
    
    play text
    
    CHARACTER: line line
    CHARACTER: line line
    
    
    KING JOHN
    
    play text
    
    CHARACTER: line line
    KING JOHN: line line
    CHARACTER: line line
    
    AS YOU LIKE IT
    
    play text
    
    CHARACTER: line line
```

What I would like to be able to do is

```
library(stringr)
text <- readLines("sample-text.txt") # contains above sample text
split_indices <- stringr::str_which(text, REGEX-THAT-I-NEED)
```

And then `text[split_indices]` should return a character vector like `c("THE SONNETS", "ALL'S WELL THAT ENDS WELL", "KING JOHN", "AS YOU LIKE IT")` instead of `c("THE SONNETS", "ALL'S WELL THAT ENDS WELL", "KING JOHN", "KING JOHN", "AS YOU LIKE IT")` which is what my current regex would return.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example to work on and show expected output for it?

Comment: @RonakShah I have added a small example. it was a little hard to do without including a bunch of text but I hope this suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only titles always upper case and contain alphabetic characters, apostrophes and spaces, and nothing else is like it, this should suffice to match titles without any false positives. Ensure your matcher has the multiline flag enabled.

**Pattern**

```regex
^\s*\b([A-Z\s']+)\b$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of line
- `\s*` May contain zero or more spaces before the title
- `\b` Word boundary
- `(` Start of capture group

  - `[A-Z\s']` Match characters A-Z, space or apostrophe

    - `+` One or more occurrences of the above token
- `)` End of capture group
- `\b` Word boundary
- `$` End of line

Comment: reading this was a facepalm moment for me...I had a list of titles so I assumed I needed to use that. But this is much better.